# Embedded image in external component?

Tags: asp.net, dll, user-controls

I am developing a drop-in component for our company's websites. This component allows users to send messages to each other.

Making this, I've hit several problems during development, such as LoadControl() not working (as it seems to be relative to the project including the  module, not the module itself).
I managed to fix this using an approach I found online, but now the next problem emerges - images.

To make the component look somewhat nice, images would be appreciated by the users for icons.
But, again, I am stuck at the same problem.

For instance, if I want an ImageButton, I would set it's ImageUrl property to "~/images/message.png", but this really references something inside my DLL and as such obviously doesn't work!

Is there a standard, good solution for this kind of problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use WebResources, look at

http://www.aspcode.net/Including-WebResource-in-ASPNET-server-control.aspx

or embedd image in control assembly as resource and serve it with http module, but you will have to declare that http module in web config of application that is using your control.